# Python: Finding number of same lists occurrences and averaging

Tags: python, list, average, defaultdict

I will explain my issue using an example:

```
A=[[1,2,10],[1,2,10],[3,4,5]]
B=[[1,2,30],[6,7,9]]
```

From these lists of lists, i would like to create a third one:

```
C=A+B
```

So i get :

```
C= [[1, 2, 10], [1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 30], [6, 7, 9]]
```

Notice that there are three lists inside `C` ,
the  `[1, 2, 10], [1, 2, 10], [1, 2, 30]` lists, which if described in terms of [x,y,z], they have the same x,y but different z.

**So i would like to have this new list:**

```
Averaged= [(1, 2, 16.666), (6, 7, 9), (3, 4, 5)]
```

where we find only one occurrence of the same x,y from lists

`[1, 2, 30], [1, 2, 40], [1, 2, 50]`

and the average of the corresponding z values `(10+10+30)/3=16.666`

I tried using `for` loops at the beginning but ended up trying to do this using `defaultdict`.

I ended up with this that keeps once the (x,y) but adds and not averages the corresponding z values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
Averaged=[]

A=[[1,2,10],[1,2,10],[3,4,5]]
B=[[1,2,30],[6,7,9]]
C=A+B
print "C=",C

ToBeAveraged= defaultdict(int)
for (x,y,z) in C:
    ToBeAveraged[(x,y)] += z
Averaged = [k + (v,) for k, v in ToBeAveraged.iteritems()]    

print 'Averaged=',Averaged
```

Is it possible to do this with defaultdict? Any ideas?

Comment: What if x and z are the same but y is different?

Comment: No, only (x,y) must be the same. To put more context to this let's say that (x,y) are coordinates and z is temperature.

Comment: Not sure how exactly, but what about matching items in a list, and if the x,y are equal, appending that element to a new list, of which you will then average the third position

Comment: I tried that but i am working with big lists and wanted to avoid creating more of them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to sort the data first:

```
>>> C = sorted(A + B)
>>> def avg(x):
        return sum(x) / len(x)

>>> [[avg(i) for i in zip(*y)] for x,y in 
     itertools.groupby(C, operator.itemgetter(0,1))]
[[1.0, 2.0, 16.666666666666668], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0, 9.0]]
```

If you just want the groups before the average:

```
[list(y) for x,y in itertools.groupby(C, operator.itemgetter(0,1))]
```

Comment: I'm getting [[1, 2, 16], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 9]]. Any idea why i get integers? I'm using Python 2.7.3.  Ok if all are integers it returns integers. It's ok.

Comment: @CosmoSurreal For python 2.x you need to converto to float. like `float(len(x))`

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are not dividing by the number of observations. I changed your code around to
collect all observations of a given pair (x, y), and then take an average of them. There should be a more efficient solution, but this should work.

```
from collections import defaultdict
Averaged=[]

A=[[1,2,10],[1,2,10],[3,4,5]]
B=[[1,2,30],[6,7,9]]
C=A+B
print "C=",C

def get_mean(x):
    return sum(ele for ele in x) / float(len(x))

ToBeAveraged= defaultdict(list)
for (x,y,z) in C:
    ToBeAveraged[(x,y)].append(z)
Averaged = [k + (get_mean(v),) for k, v in ToBeAveraged.iteritems()]    

print 'Averaged=',Averaged
```

Result:

```
C= [[1, 2, 10], [1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 30], [6, 7, 9]]
Averaged= [(1, 2, 16.666666666666668), (6, 7, 9.0), (3, 4, 5.0)]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am not yet used to what defaultdict can achieve and this is quite an eye opener.